# Add a scrollbar in a huge dropdown menu

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, scrollbar

I am currently working in my website and I am having issues with my responsive design menu. The problem is this menu includes a lot of stuff and when you open it the content disappears from the screen area and there is no way to see the whole list. How can I add an scroll bar in that menu? Or at least, can I add some up and down arrows?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: We need some code to help you.

Comment: welcome to community! Please provide code snippets.

Comment: Here, the example http://prntscr.com/9mfbqp

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.menu{
overflow-y:scroll;
height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kashif, I tried with you code but it does not add a scroll bar... see example: http://prntscr.com/9mfem4. I am trying to include another bar to scroll in the menu you can see in the example.

Comment: ahh yes, but this style would be useful in small screens, what are you using for desktop?

Answer (score 0):

For horizontal menu:

```
.horizonal_menu {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

For vertical menu:

```
.vertical_menu {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

where `auto` adds a scroll bar only when necessary, that is - if items are clipped by default.
Please refer to [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) for more CSS `overflow` information.